# Use different filters on different pandas data frames on each loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning python in order to automate some tasks at my work. What I need to do is to read many big TSV files and use filter each one of them on a list of keys that may be different from a TSV to another and then return the result in an Excel report using certain template. In order to do that I load at once all the common data to all the files: the list of TSV files to process, some QC values, the filter to be used for each TSV then in a loop I read all the files that I need to process and load one TSV on each loop round in pandas data frame then filter and fill the Excel report. The problem is that the filter does not seem to work and I am getting Excel files of the same length each time (number of rows)!!. I suspect that the data frame does not get reinitialized on each round but trying to del the df and releasing the memory do not work as well. How can I solve the issue? Is there a better data structure to handle my problem. Below a part of the code.
Thanks

```
# This how I load the filter for each file in each round of the the loop (as an array)
target = load_workbook(target_input)
target_sheet = target.active    
targetProbes = []
for k in range (2, target_sheet.max_row+1):
    targetProbes.append(target_sheet.cell(k, 1).value)
# This is how I load each TSV file in each round of the loop (an df)
tsv_reader = pd.read_csv(calls, delimiter='\t', comment = '#', low_memory=False)

# This is how I filter the df based on the filter
tsv_reader = tsv_reader[tsv_reader['probeset_id'].isin(targetProbes)]
tsv_reader.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

# This how I try to del the df and clear the current filter so I can re-use them for another TSV file with different values in the next round of the loop
del tsv_reader
targetProbes.clear()
```

Comment: I do not understand. Is there a loop around this snipped or where do you change the file to read? Where does `calls` come from?

Comment: Hello. Yes there is a loop but I did not want to put the whole code as it is quite long

Comment: so it is like `for calls in ...`?